# How to properly finish basement walls with an indoor waterproofing membrane?

Tags: basement, waterproofing, basement-insulation

The house I moved into has an ~1800 sq. ft. unfinished basement which has been waterproofed on the inside, halfway up the walls all around it, taped to insulation put on the upper half like this:
[image: Basement walls]

*I don't think they did a good job because the tape is literally holding the membrane up lol.*

My question is, how do I properly finish these walls to make this a liveable basement?

I'm assuming whatever they did with the insulation is incorrect so I know that needs to come off, however, can I just install a rigid foam product over the top of the membrane/walls? Would it even stick to it? Or is something else needed?

From what I've read, I need to install a rigid foam board on the exterior walls, then the framing and fill those in with proper insulation; first, is this correct and second, will this work in my situation?

As an aside, if I don't plan on finishing this project any time soon, should the insulation and barrier come off or is it fine for now? And if it should come off, how will the membrane stay up now that the tape to the barrier is removed?

Comment: usually you frame it out from bottom plate to top plate, add studs, run wiring, then drywall. I might consider carpeting the walls too, it's durable, it insulates, and it makes the space much quieter. I saw that done on a McMansion and it worked really well. Tapestries hiding what you have would achieve some of that for cheaper and easier.